# In IBM Lotus Notes PutInFolder() methods mail document in $Sent or $Drafts view?

Tags: runtime-error, lotus-notes

While Putting mail in folder it automatically added in $Drafts or $Sent.

```
objdoc = m_objNotesDBDst.CreateDocument();                                        
objth.t_CurrentDoc.CopyAllItems(objdoc, true);    
objdoc.Save(true, false, true);
objdoc.PutInFolder(objth.t_PutInFolder, true);
```

Comment: objdoc.PutInFolder("$Trash");     is not added in trash folder why

Answer (score 2):

**$Drafts** and **$Sent** are not folder, they are views.

> On the surface, views and folders look the same. Both display
>   documents vertically in rows, and for each row there are columns which
>   show information about the document. For example, your Inbox (which is
>   a folder) and All Documents (which is a view) both show emails, and
>   the columns for each row display values such as the name of the
>   Sender, the date, the size, and the subject.
>
> Where a Folder and View differ, is in how they determine which
>   documents to display.
>
> Each view in a database, such as your mailbox, is pre-configured by a
>   developer to show documents based on something called a "Selection
>   Formula". That formula can range from something as simple as "All", so
>   that every document in a database is shown, to a very granular formula
>   such as "Show me all documents by a specific author, and are older
>   than a specific date, and over a specific size".
>
> Folders on the other hand are more of an "open container" for
>   documents. Instead of displaying documents based on any specific
>   criteria, they display just those documents that you drag and drop
>   into them, or redirect from your Inbox using Mail Rules. Folders tend
>   to be more personal, and allow you to define your own way to store
>   documents, organized in a manner which has meaning specific to you.
>
> Examples of views in your mailbox: All Documents, Sent, Drafts
>
> Examples of folders in your mailbox: Inbox, 5 Weeks, Junk, trash, all
>   folders that you created to file your messages (they appear under the
>   label "Folders")

original article you can find here: [What is the difference between a View and a Folder in Lotus Notes?](http://web4.uwindsor.ca/its/faq/id/401)

In order to check what is folder and what is view you need to open database in designer.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your code makes a copy of current document with all items and puts it into a folder.

If your current document is a mail which was sent then your copy will be a sent mail too and appear in view **$Sent** as it has all items from current document. $Sent's selection formula is

```
SELECT DeliveredDate = "" & PostedDate != "" & !(@IsMember("S"; ExcludeFromView))
```

If you don't want to appear your copy document in view $Sent then add this line of code after CopyAllItems line:

```
objdoc.replaceItemValue("ExcludeFromView"; "S");
```

If your current document is a draft then your copy will be a draft too and appear in view **$Drafts** as it has all items from current document. $Drafts's selection formula is

```
SELECT PostedDate = "" & $MessageType = "" & @IsNotMember("D" : "A"; ExcludeFromView) & 
ISMAILSTATIONERY != 1 & Form != "Group" & Form != "Person"
```

If you don't want to appear your copy document in view $Drafts then add this line of code after CopyAllItems line:

```
objdoc.replaceItemValue("ExcludeFromView"; "D");
```

---

In case you just want to put the current document into folder without creating a copy then change your code to this one line:

```
objth.t_CurrentDoc.PutInFolder(objth.t_PutInFolder, true);
```

Comment: Why i get Note Error:Collection is busy

Comment: Note Error:Index Entry Not Found

Comment: : Notes error: Cannot write or create file (file or disk is read-only)

Comment: int total=NotViewobj.AllEntries.Count;

Comment: Cannot write or create file (file or disk is read-only)   gets problem when GetView(FileName)

Comment: Index Entry Not Found   when- objNotesDoc=objNotesView.GetNextDocument(objPrevDoc);